# How to represent a tree in string format?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, format

Let's take for example this sequence of moves:

line 1: `1. Rxe8+ Rxe8 2. Qxe8#` line 2: `1. Qxe8+ Rxe8 2. Rxe8#`

I can represent this with JSON:

```
{
  'Rxe8+': {
    'Rxe8': {
      'Qxe8#': {}
    }
  },
  'Qxe8+': {
    'Rxe8': {
      'Rxe8#': {}
    }
  }
}
```

Can you suggest a simple format to specify this combination lines in string?

Comment: Is that really the format you want to use? A really long nested object of nested object?

Comment: why not take a space (or any other delimiter) spearated string for each line? or an array?

Comment: As far as a String format, unless you're going to use an encryption or compression algorithm, I agree with @NinaScholz - there's a reason csv type formatting is used so frequently. Regardless of the delimiter you use, they're easy to read, import/export, and edit. Best not to overthink and keep it simple.

Comment: Well lines can have sublines like a tree @NinaScholz

Comment: JSON is a string representation of a tree structure. XML is also a string representation of a tree structure. There are many others that are less well known, for example S-expressions. Why do you need something new?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be to override the JSON functionality (JSON.stringify will implicitly call `.toJSON`), so you can define a custom one and use that.

```js
var sequence = "1. Rxe8+ Rxe8 2. Qxe8#";

function MoveList(sequence){
    this.sequence = sequence;
}
MoveList.prototype.toJSON = function(){ 
 var moveSet = {};
 var moves = this.sequence.split(" ");
 for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i+=3){
     var moveNumber = moves[i];
     var whiteMove = moves[i+1];
     var blackMove = moves[i+2];
     moveSet[moveNumber] = {
      "White" : whiteMove
     };
     if(blackMove) moveSet[moveNumber].Black = blackMove;
 }
 return moveSet;
};

var ml = new MoveList(sequence);
var mlJson = JSON.stringify(ml);
console.log(mlJson); // As actual JSON
console.log(JSON.parse(mlJson)); // back in object form
```

Answer (score -2):

As I don't quite understand what you're asking, I believe you're looking for the native Javascript function `JSON.parse` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp.

```js
var stringifiedJson = JSON.stringify({hello: "test"});
```

The variable stringifiedJson would return `{"hello": "test"}`.
If you're perhaps searching for how to represent something in text rather than a programming language, try XML. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/.

```xml
<Rxe8+>
    <Rxe8>
        <Qxe8#>
        </Qxe8#>
    </Rxe8>
</Rxe8+>
```

etc.